# Duplicate record issue using hibernate

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, concurrency

We have seen an issue, we have two different web apps which tend to register user.

The user table is having userId as primary key and is set to auto-increment in MYSQL database.

When inserted from one webapp if we try to insert from another web app **almost instantaneously** then we get a error entity user with some id already exists. Duplicate primary key.

These two web app run on two different server but have same database, hibernate session and session factory of both applications is different and could possible not sharing sessions causing this issue?

Or anything else which we are unable to track. Please help.

Comment: Show the relevant code, the table definition, and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? **[edit]** your question and add the complete `create table` statement for the table in question and the code that generates the PK value (if it's in your code)